# Binning Pandas column values by standard deviation centered on average?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a Pandas data frame with a bunch of values in sorted order:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,21))
```

I want to end up with a list/array like this:

```
[0,1.62,4.58,7.54,10.5,13.45,16.4,19.37,20]
```

The first and last element are `df.min()` and `df.max()`, the center element is the `df.mean()` of the dataframe, and the surrounding elements are all in increments in of `0.5*df.std()`

Is there a way to vectorize this for large DataFrames?

UPDATE (Efficient method is in the answers below!)

```
a = np.arange(df[0].mean(),df[0].min(),-0.5*df[0].std())
b = np.arange(df[0].mean(),df[0].max(),0.5*df[0].std())
c = np.concatenate((a,b))
c = np.append(c,[df[0].min(),df[0].max()])
c = np.unique(c)
```

And then use `np.digitize()` to move values to appropriate bins.

If you find a more efficient way though, that would be helpful!

Comment: Share your loopy implementation?

Comment: @Divakar, added code example

Comment: Not sure if I am assuming something wrong, but that code doesn't run, does it? Throws error at : `if x > df.min():`?

Comment: Yeah I realized that was terrible code and just got to a console to test it out. Too crappy to keep up so I removed it and will add to the question next time I get the chance :/ Sorry!

Comment: @piRSquared Sorry, that was a dumb typo. Can you look at the updated solution I proposed and see if that makes sense?

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks for that, it does work and I'll mark it as answered. I didn't understand the code, and don't want to include code in my work that I don't understand how it works. It'll take a me a bit to understand but it does work.

Comment: I've simplified the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mu_sig` calculates various multiples of standard deviations by multiplying `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]` by sigma.

`edges` takes a series and gets `mu_sig` results.  Then checks to see that the series minimum is less then minimum multiple of standard deviation less the mean.  If it is, then prepend it to list.  Do the same check for max.

```
def edges(s, n=7, rnd=2, sig_mult=1):
    mu = s.mean()
    sig = s.std()
    mn = s.min()
    mx = s.max()

    sig = np.arange(-n // 2, (n + 1) // 2 + 1) * sig * sig_mult
    ms = (mu + sig)

    # Checking if mins and maxs are in range of sigs
    if mn < ms.min():
        ms = np.concatenate([[mn], ms])
    if mx > max(ms):
        ms = np.concatenate([ms, [mx]])

    return ms.round(rnd).tolist()
```

It works on a series, so I'll squeeze your dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,21))
s = df.squeeze()
```

Then use `edges`

## THIS IS YOUR ANSWER

```
edges(s, sig_mult=.5, n=5)

[1, 1.63, 4.58, 7.54, 10.5, 13.46, 16.42, 19.37, 20]
```

---

```
edges(s)

[1, -13.16, -7.25, -1.33, 4.58, 10.5, 16.42, 22.33, 28.25, 34.16, 20]
```

This returns a list of length 11 by default.  You can pass `n` to get different length lists.

```
edges(s, n=3)

[1, -1.33, 4.58, 10.5, 16.42, 22.33, 20]
```

Anticipating that you may want to change this to different multiples of standard deviation, you can also do:

```
edges(df, n=3, sig_mult=.2)

[1, 8.13, 9.32, 10.5, 11.68, 12.87, 20]
```

---

#### Timing

**Series of length 20**

[image]

**Series of length 1,000,000**

[image]